# Cannot install PyTorch with Python 3.11 (Windows)

Tags: python, pip, pytorch, python-3.11

I recently upgraded to Python 3.11 and proceeded to install the libraries I typically use for 3.11. I went through my list one by one with `pip`.

When I tried to install PyTorch, I got an error which says:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch
```

None of the suggestions I could find on pytorch.com resolved the issue.

What went wrong, and what do I need to do in order to install PyTorch properly?

Comment: It works now on Windows too!

Answer (score 11):

As of now, PyTorch only provides a Linux build with python 3.11
You can check all available wheels here.

https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch/

Answer (score 5):

I saw this issue on github: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/86566 it looks like PyTorch doesn't support 3.11 yet.
Apparently there's a nightly build that you can try to use, I haven't tested it though.

Comment: Nightly build for Python 3.11 is only available on Linux at present

Answer (score 5):

This works for me. Installs the nightly version of torch.

```
pip install --pre torch -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/nightly/cpu/torch_nightly.html
```

Comment: worked for me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

[**TL;DR**] In general, to get full Python 3.11 support it's advisable to **upgrade `torch` to version 2.x**.

---

*More info*

From my installation experience the compatibility matrix of `torch` vs. Python vs. OS type vs. CUDA version vs. `torchvision` version has been pretty complex during the switch from `torch` 1.x to 2.x:

The *earliest* version of **`torch` supporting Python 3.11**:

- under Linux was 1.13.0 (unless you wanted also `torchvision`, then 2.0.0)
- under Windows was 2.0.0
- under CUDA 11.5 or earlier was None
- under CUDA (11.6 or 11.7) was (1.13.0 and 1.13.1)
- under CUDA 11.8 was 2.0.0
- under CUDA 12.x is still None
- with `torchvision` under Linux or Windows was 2.0.0 (this is because the 1st version of `torchvision` compatible with Python 3.11 is `torchvision==0.15.0+cu117`, which depends on `torch==2.0.0+cu117`)

Comment: so does that mean you'll need torch 2.0.0 at least for python3.11 on Windows...  but if your version of CUDA is 10.1 then you have no options to install? I have an older Nivida K2100M processor which i think I read that latest driver in 2020 maxes out at CUDA 10.1